# How do I name controllers which are related to multiple entities in REST?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, controller, naming-conventions, naming

I want to rename and re-route controllers to make them more "RESTful", and I encountered a problem. Let's say I have `ItemsController`, the route is `api/items`. Then I have VersionsController, `api/versions`. I also have `VersionItemsConroller`, which is a separate entity. And I also have a controller with this route: `api/versions/{versionId:int}/items` for, let's say, getting items of specific version (or anything that involves operations with items that are related to specific version), and I don't know how to properly name it, since `VersionItemsMappingController` seems ugly. Is there a naming convention or some kind of best practice for such cases?

Comment: As a quick reaction, perhaps one should question why there's both an `items` resource and a `versions/123/items` resource? Isn't that confusing to users of the API?

Comment: you dont need create a `controller` for specific version  just create action  with specific route in  `Itemscontroller` like `/api/items/10/version/1`

Comment: @MarkSeemann Items is a basic crud with get, post, put and delete. versions/{id}/items is for actions that are not basic crud and are related to items of specific version. not sure about confusing part, honestly

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh version here is a business entity, not api version

Comment: I also understood that it is an entity and that the ROUTE I gave is correct If I wanted to add the API version to it, I would write : `/api/v1/items/10/version/1`

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh it's not for a specific version, id is a parameter. Your approach is ok I think and I thought about something similar, just wanted to try to do it this way. If what I want to do is incorrect (though as I understood it's also acceptable), I'll probably do something similar

Comment: I would put the version as a query string of a route inside `ItemsController` and discard all the other two controllers: `/api/items?version=1`

Comment: @SergioJr  `version`  is Entity

Answer (score 2):

Since `api/versions/{versionId:int}/items` is about getting items of a specific **version**, it is better to place the appropriate method to the `VersionsController`.

Thus, the entire structure will look like this:

**ItemsController:**

- `api/items`

**VersionsController:**

- `api/versions`
- `api/versions/{versionId:int}/items`

**VersionItemsConroller:**

- `api/version-tems`